# API xStation XTB, handshaking with Postman

Tags: json, authentication, postman, handshake

I'm new to using Postman.

I have successfully used the XTB sample code in Python to login and request data via xapi.xtb.com [Python Wrapper](http://developers.xstore.pro/public/files/xAPI25-XTB-python.zip)

However, for learning purposes, I have not succeeded in doing a login via Postman. For example, as far as I read on the [documentation](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/), in Postman, I created a POST request to xapi.xtb.com:5124, adding to the Body the JSON needed for login, i.e.:

```json
{
    "command" : "login",
    "arguments" : {
        "userId" : "1000",
        "password": "PASSWORD"
    }
}
```

After clicking the "Send" button, I received an error message: "Error: socket hang up".

Should I use another parameter for a successful login? (changing the authorisation type or anything else?)

While connecting using the sample Python code, I observed a more complex set of messages between my local computer and the remote XTB server in Wireshark. I am doubtful about whether it is possible to do this login request via Postman or any other requests.

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.